# Isolating/separating vocals from audio by FFMPEG

Tags: ffmpeg

I remove the vocals from music via

`ffmpeg -i song.mp3 -af pan="stereo|c0=c0|c1=-1*c1" -ac 1 karaoke.mp3`

The output is the music without vocals (not completely but fairly good).

I wonder what is the command to make the output separated vocals (vocal only)?

I mean how to save the separated vocals in an audio file?

I mean how to save the separated vocals in an audio file?
I want to remove only instrumental music without vocal from audio file by ffmpeg.
Please someone help me.

Comment: Short answer, it's impossible, that's also the reason that https://superuser.com/questions/1408044/ has no acceptable answer for over 4 years.